# OSError: [Errno 2] No such file/directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, adafruit-circuitpython

I am trying to load a font on the Circuitpy using Python and when I run the code I get this error 
 File "code.py", line, 81, in 
 File "/lib/adafruit_bitmap_font/bitmap_font.py",
 line 44 in load_font
 OSError: [Errno 2] No such file/directory

The code in that spot is

```
def load_font(filename, bitmap=None):
    """Loads a font file. Returns None if unsupported."""
    if not bitmap:
        import displayio
        bitmap = displayio.Bitmap
    font_file = open(filename, "rb")    # This is the error spot <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    first_four = font_file.read(4)
    # print(first_four)
    if filename.endswith("bdf") and first_four == b"STAR":
        from . import bdf
        return bdf.BDF(font_file, bitmap)
    if filename.endswith("pcf") and first_four == b"\x01fcp":
        import pcf
        return pcf.PCF(font_file)
    if filename.endswith("ttf") and first_four == b"\x00\x01\x00\x00":
        import ttf
        return ttf.TTF(font_file)
    return None
```

All I am trying to do is load the font. We are making an alarm clock in class and I got the code off of the Adafruit website but I am trying to add code to it so it works. I have never coded before so I don't know what I am doing. I am running this code on a pyportal.

What should I do to fix this?

**Edit: Ok So I need to define filename, how do I do that so that it will register as the different fonts that I will be using? ***

Comment: Isn't error message obvious?

Comment: @OlvinRoght I don't code and don't know what I am doing. From my understanding it opens the file depending on what the code specifies in the other code I have. But that is just my guess. How would you fix it?

Comment: What is the filename?  The error says that it doesn't exist, so that could be part of the problem.  How are you running the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I did not have the fonts in the right folder so the pathway was not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have that font installed?

`ls /lib/adafruit_bitmap_font/`

and make sure that `bitmap_font.py` is there.

Also, where did you define `filename`